# How to find out if a string is random in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, encryption, random, statistics

I am working on some Encryption witch create a encrypted string like 
`t7AZChkiBA` or `?t7AZDxknCE34F14OuwuXiIcGBIKqSGya03CY9cf9iUSPuCb7owPUzmfTxoBsDzE533S82dvKqm7KmOkREtknHH30z6rLHAHg29COKjX9A6uZxh4fAlrRy`

The length is not fixed. How can I find if this string is random and does not mean something?
I don't have a dictionary. I am trying to find some statistical correlation, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: This may be a help: https://www.random.org/analysis/ it has links to tests for *randomness*.

Comment: If you get this string from a program, by definition it will never be random... It holds the meaning through decryption

Comment: @ Eregrith: Unless it gets its data from a True Random Number Generator. But for encryption purposes there are often platform specific Random Number Generators which have been found to be non-deterministic enough to be valid to use in the context of AES and the like, `SecureRandom` being one of them.

Comment: @Eregrith: I don't follow your point: programs can provide meaningfully random outputs (based on entropy from mouse movements, webcam sensors, effectively unpredictable timings etc.), and such data has no meaning and can not be decrypted given it's not an encryption of anything to begin with.

Comment: @ sam: Look into (information) entropy, which is in some sense a measure for randomness/uncertainty.

Comment: @ Tony D: Using sensor data might be very helpful when generating random numbers, but you can't use any sensor. Depending on its resolution and sampling rate, your random numbers might not be that random after all and you'll be introducing a pattern into the random data.

Comment: Encryption is, by defintion, decryptable. The output is only as random as the input.

Comment: @potAito: certainly an issue, though rather than "can't use any [such] sensor" I'd say don't want to *rely* on any such sensor: if you xor as many sources as possible the quality increases - the only inputs that are so bad as to be totally useless are all-0 and all-1 and no inputs can cause actual harm - but you do ideally want at least one consistently good source.

Comment: @Eregrith: if you receive encrypted data that was encrypted by xor-ing with a truly random one time pad, then it is not decryptable by you without that pad and is itself truly random too.

Comment: @sam: you ask *"How can I find if this string is random and does not mean something?"* - what exactly do you mean? What kind of non-random string are you concerned about? Do you mean that it might *coincidentally* contain some words or discernable pattern? Why would you care?

Comment: @TonyD "*...and is itself truly random too*". You should stop there to define "random" or else this debate is pointless.

Comment: @Eregrith: I'll settle for pointless... as I don't think we're heading anywhere else, and anyone else reading this can make what they will of the existing comments.  Cheers.

Comment: @TonyD Fine by me. Have a nice day

Comment: Not sure if this is possible. Randomness is everything. It may even return a string containing your question

Comment: Totally impossible. "Randomness" analysis is meaningless with a piece of data that small. There *is* a simple way to roughly measure the amount of entropy in a string of bits, though: compress it. The higher entropy it began with, the less compressible it will be.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this website, which has an online calculator of Shannon's entropy for an arbitrary string, a formula, and a quite good explanation will help:

http://www.shannonentropy.netmark.pl/

From that calculator, what you are looking for is the "metric entropy", which equals Shannon's enthropy divided by the string length, which is a measure of the randomness of your string. It can take values  between 0 and 1, where 1 means that the string is equally distributed random.

Answer (score 1):

The string is not a random bit string. It seems to consist entirely of characters in some kind of alphabet. The characters may be part of some kind of fully randomized input set though.

To really test for randomness you need to translate your ciphertext to a bit string. Then get one of the test applications defined by NIST or the German BSI to test for randomness and use the bit string as input.

To determine that it is *not* random you could run frequency analysis or determine if the Hamming distance is significantly different from 0.5 over the ciphertext. If I take a good look at your random text it is very likely that one of these tests fails. Although there are many other tests, you only need one failing test to show that it is *not* random.

Of course, as any bit string is equally likely for random text, you can only show with a certain level of confidence that it is not random.

Furthermore, it is entirely possible to fool random number tests. The fact that ciphertext passes these tests doesn't mean that the cipher withstands targeted attacks at all.

Answer (score 0):

One technique - which would work better with longer strings - would be to generate a very large set of random sample strings, then calculate some statistics on them to get a sense of the average and standard deviation for random input, which would let you get a crude percentage chance of any given input string *not* being random.  Combinating such tests - each using a different statistic - should give you a more accurate test.

As for what the statistics could be, it may depend a bit on what kind of non-random input you expect (e.g. whether you need to "protect" against a user engineering non-random input designed to fool your program):

- average "distance" (subtracting ASCII values) between adjacent letters
- number of samples in different ranges (e.g. break A-Za-z0-9 into 10 ranges and see if the # character in each range is as even as it must be for random inputs)
- count how often any subsequence repeats later in the string, possibly reversed
- count of dictionary words, possibly with a minimum length to avoid noise
- checking whether uppercase letters, lower-case consonants, lower-case vowels, numbers appear roughly in proportion to the number of such characters in the input format (e.g. if you have 52 characters and 10 digits = 62 possible character values, you'd expect lower-case vowels to average 5/62 of the string length, and could calculate a standard deviation to tell you how significant a higher/lower value was
- checking how often particular bits in the incoming characters are set

Answer (score 0):

One way of separating random from non-random is to try compressing the string.  A non-random string will compress more than a random string.  Of course, the issue with a string produced by a good encryption method is that any such method is *designed* to output strings that appear random, and so will pass many tests for randomness.  Even decrypting with the wrong key will still give a random output.